# Does numpy.random.seed make results fixed on different computers?

Tags: python, numpy

I know that when you use `numpy.random.seed(0)` you get the same result on your own computer every time. I am wondering if it is also true for different computers and different installations of numpy.

Comment: Compatibility Guarantee A fixed seed and a fixed series of calls to ‘RandomState’ methods using the same parameters will always produce the same results up to roundoff error except when the values were incorrect. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState

Comment: What happened when you tried it on different computers?
What did you not understand from the documentation's explanation of the topic?

Comment: @Prune I have not tried it on different computers. I wanted to know whether I can rely on this. The documentations always point the fact that with the same seed you will generate the same numbers, but I think they mean with the same computer + current installation of numpy. I do not see the guarantee of being same between different computers + different installations.

Comment: Please include your research in the question to clarify the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends upon type of `algorithm` implemented internally by `numpy random function`. In case of `numpy`, which is operated by `pseudo-random number generators` (PRNGs) algorithm. What this means is that if you provide the same seed( as of starting input ), you will get the same output. And if you change the seed, you will get a different output. So this kind of algorithm is no system dependent.

But for a `true random number generator (TRNG)` these often rely on some kind of specialized hardware that does some physical measurement of something unpredictable in the environment such as light or temperature electrical noise radioactive material. So if an module implements t
his kind of algorithm then it will be system dependent.

Comment: Can you add a link to the source of the quoted paragraph? Does that mean that it is guaranteed to be the same across different computers + different numpy installations? I am a little confused.

Comment: I just execute it on my local host, server console and also in VM with different python version but result was same. I was just differentiating between PRNGs and TRNGs in your answer context so that you can get an idea what is going under that hood.  [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState).